# Measure theory, notation

Tags: measure-theory, notation

This is from Avner Friedman's "Foundations of Modern Analysis":

> Let $\mu$ be a measure with domain $A$ and let $E_n$ ($n=1,2...$) be sets of $A$. Then $\mu (\underline{\mathrm{lim}}_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_n) \leq \underline{\mathrm{lim}}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n)$ and $\mu (\overline{\mathrm{lim}}_{n \rightarrow \infty} E_n) \geq \overline{\mathrm{lim}}_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mu(E_n)$, provided $\mu (\cup E_n) < \infty$.

The underline and overline, what do they mean? Thank you.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/12497/31729

Comment: That is to say, overline means lim sup and underline means lim inf? Got it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it didn't occur to me to write that!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Definition_for_sequences